# SQLite in development, PostgreSQL in production—why not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

Heroku advises against this because of possible issues. I'm an SQL noob, can you explain the type of issues that could be encountered by using different databases?

Comment: For one you don't get a lot of the nicer features of PostgreSQL. Not that this matters much if you're just using ActiveRecord all the time and not anything more complicated. Bugs and performance problems can be a lot harder to trace, though.

Comment: SQLite is strongly idiosyncratic, and for instance doesn't really fully support SQL data types beyond the bare minimum. For instance, if you use a decimal column with a precision and scale set, SQLite will just ignore those and do… something, while Postgres woll round values you're saving. Another thing is that SQLite doesn't have length-constrained string columns. There's probably many more differences which will make the two behave differently in unpredictable edge cases that will make for amusing bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different databases interpret and adhere to the SQL standard differently. If you were to, say, copy paste some code from SQLite to PostgreSQL there's a very large chance that it won't immediately work. If it's only basic queries, then maybe, but when dealing with anything particular there's a very low chance of complete compatability.

Some databases are also more up to date with the standard. It's a similar battlefield to that of internet browsers. If you've ever made some websites you'd know compatability is a pain in the ass, having to get it to work for older versions and Internet Explorer. Because some databases are older than others, and some even older than the standards, they would've had their own way of doing things which they can't just scrap and jump to the standard because they would lose support for their existing larger customers (this is especially the case with a database engine called Oracle). PostgreSQL is sort of like Google Chrome, quite high up there on standards compliance but still with some of its own little quirks. SQLite is, as the name suggests, a light-weight database system. You could assume it lacks some of the more advanced functionality from the standards.

The database engines also perform the same actions differently. It is worth getting to know and understand one database and how it works (deeper than just the query level) so you can make the most of that.

Answer (score 16):

I used sqlite3 in development and postgres in production for a while, but recently switched to postgres everywhere.

Things to note if you use both:

- There are differences between sqlite3 and postgres that will bite you. A common thing I ran into is that postgres is stricter about types in queries (`where :string_column => <integer>` will work fine in sqlite and break in postgres). You definitely want a staging area that uses postgres if your dev is sqlite and it matters if your production app goes down because of a sql error.
- Sqlite is **much** easier to set up on your local machine, and it's great being able to just delete/move .sqlite files around in your db/ directory.
- `taps` allows you to mirror your heroku postgres data into your local sqlite db. It gets much slower as the database gets larger, and at a few 10s of tables and 100K+ rows it starts to take 20+ minutes to restore.
- You won't get postgres features like ilike, the new key/value stores, fulltext search
- Because you have to use only widely supported SQL features, it may be easier to migrate your app to mysql

So why did I switch? I wanted some postgres-only features, kept hitting bugs that weren't caught by testing, and needed to be able to mirror my production db faster (pg_restore takes ~1 minute vs 20+ for taps).  My advice is to stay with sqlite in dev because of the simplicity, and then switch when/if you need to down the road. Switching from sqlite to postgres for development is as simple as setting up postgres - there's no added complexity from waiting.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a (kind of) similar situation. Generally it is a very bad idea to use different database engines for production and test. There are multiple reasons

- SQL syntax differences including DML, DDL statements, stored procedures, triggers etc
- Performance optimizations done on one DB wont be valid on the other
- SQLite is an embedded database, PostgreSQL is not
- They don't support the same data types
- Different syntax/commands to configure/setup db. SQLite uses PRAGMAs

One should stick to one db engine, unless you have a really, really good reason. I can't think of any.