# heroku error PG::Error: ERROR: function strftime(unknown, timestamp without time zone) does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have following sql in my controller:

```
@tot_expense = Expense.where("strftime('%m', created_at) + 0 = ?", Time.now.strftime("%m").to_i).sum("amount")
```

This works fine in my development environment. But after deploying in heroku it gives me the below error while saving the record.

> PG::Error: ERROR:  function strftime(unknown, timestamp without time
>   zone) does not exist

I have uncommented 
`config.time_zone = 'UTC'` in my `config/application.rb` file but it didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to extract month from created_at field, please use extract sql function.

```
  @tot_expense = Expense.where("extract(month from created_at) + 0 = ?", Time.now.strftime("%m").to_i).sum("amount")
```

Comment: Thanks it worked on heroku but not on development probably because sqlite dose not understand 'extract'..

Comment: @Sumy, you need to use PostgreSQL on local development, it's not good to use different databases for development and production environment. Please refer this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859186/sqlite-in-development-postgresql-in-production-why-not