# how do I continue my app after deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ide, hosting, share

So I have deployed my rails app on a VPS with Ubuntu Server and Apache,
following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04) . Everything is working perfectly except that I'm not sure on how to continue to develop my app, bitbucket  is configured and working but I don't want to commit and push every time since I make a lot of try and errors. So I'm looking for an easy way to continue to develop and test.

I will appreciate any answers and recommendations , thank you.

Comment: If you deployed the application as production you can set that section as master. If you want to keep working on it, you could work from features under the develop branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep building your into local machine.

1. Create a branch `git checkout -b branch_name`

You can make changes and test this branch.

2. `git add -A`
3. `git commit -m "Suitable message"`
4. `git checkout master`
5. `git pull origin master`
6. `git merge branch_name`
7. `git push origin master`

P.S : You can continue your development in `master` branch too.

Comment: OK perfect thank you ! But now i'm having a small problem , I cloned my project in my local machine but I don't have the database entries that are on my hosted website. ( i'm using sqlite )

Comment: @keke: If you would like to do testing using live DB, then take a dump of it. Or you can create tables and fill values.

Comment: @keke, also the best DB setup for a live rails apps is by using `postgres` for production. As `sqlite` have some limitation, which can lead to `sql` errors. Check detail: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859186/sqlite-in-development-postgresql-in-production-why-not/10859232#10859232>